# Invalid Request in orangeHrm

Tags: php, symfony, orangehrm

I have created my new **custom plugin in orangehrm** which is developed by symfony framework. When I load this url 'http://localhost/orangehrm/symfony/web/index.php/kpa/searchKpa' and it display error *'Invalid Request'*.

[see my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIYXC.png)

Another questions are **'where does from plugin or orangehrm module starts work'**, **'how does orangehrm plugin work'** and **'from which file it may starts work'**.

```
public function initialize() {
        $enabledModules = sfConfig::get('sf_enabled_modules');
        if (is_array($enabledModules)) {
            sfConfig::set('sf_enabled_modules', array_merge(sfConfig::get('sf_enabled_modules'), array('kpa')));
        }
    }
```

**It works, also I have prints the message inside the initialize function, but after it print statement didn't work.**

Answer (score 0):

**Check all directory name ans this is the issue i have found.**

In my project directory under modules directory are *kpa->actions, templates*. But before it *process->actions, templates*.